# PyQt5 Signal and Slot will not fire and hangs Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a UI I built in QDesigner and when I try to connect the signal and the slot, Python gives the following error:

TypeError: connect() failed between clicked(bool) and loadClicked()

If I remove the @pyqtSlot() designer, the UI will launch, but when I click the button, Python errors out and shuts down. What could be causing the issue?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
import cv2
import sys

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
    # Other UI Setup and config attributes
    self.SelectImage.clicked.connect(self.loadClicked)

@pyqtSlot()
def loadClicked(self):
    super(self.loadImage("Wilkerson.png"))

def loadImage(self, fname):
    self.image = cv2.imread(fname)
    self.displayImage()

def displayImage(self):
    qformat=QImage.Format_Indexed8
    if len(self.image.shape) == 3:
        if (self.image.shape[2]) == 4:
            qformat = QImage.Format_RGBA8888
        else:
            qformat = QImage.Format_RGB888
    img = QImage(self.image, self.image.shape[1], self.image.shape[0], self.image.strides[0], qformat)
    img = img.rgbSwapped()
    self.importedImageFrame.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(img))
    self.importedImageFrame.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
```

I got rid of the QDesigner UI code and tried to just import the UI file. It still hasn't fixed the issue. The revised code is below.

```
class ezNPR(QDialog):
def __init__(self):
    super(ezNPR,self).__init__()
    loadUi('ezNPRApp.ui',self)
    self.Image=None
    # Insert Application control commands here
    self.AppStackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
    self.ExitPushButton.clicked.connect(QDialog.close)
    self.ImagePushButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.AppStackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0))
    self.SignaturePushButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.AppStackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1))
    self.HelpPushButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.AppStackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(2))
    self.SelectImage.clicked.connect(self.loadClicked)
    self.setWindowTitle("ezNPR Image and Photo Cropping Tool")

@pyqtSlot()
def loadClicked(self):
    fname, filter = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", 'C:\\', "Image Files (*.jpg,*.png,*.bmp,*.tif)")
    if fname:
        self.loadImage(fname)
    else:
        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        msg.setText("Invalid image type selected. Please select a new image.")
        msg.setInformativeText("You must selct a BMP, JPG, PNG, or TIFF")
        msg.setWindowTitle("Error Loading Image")
        msg.setStandardButtons(msg.Ok)

def loadImage(self, fname):
    self.displayImage()
    self.image = cv2.imread(fname)

def displayImage(self):
    qformat = QImage.Format_Indexed8
    if len(self.image.shape) == 3:
        if (self.image.shape[2]) == 4:
            qformat = QImage.Format_RGBA8888
        else:
            qformat = QImage.Format_RGB888
    img = QImage(self.image, self.image.shape[1], self.image.shape[0], self.image.strides[0], qformat)
    img = img.rgbSwapped()
    self.importedImageFrame.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(img))
    self.importedImageFrame.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
```

I went back and re-looked at a few things and was able to work out the problem. However, Now I have encountered a new problem of not being able to get the output image to fit in the QDsigner Label I created to display the image. The pre-transformed image displays, but it is not scaled to fit the label. My code is hanging at the second to last line in the display_image function...

```
import sys, traceback
import os
import cv2
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QFileDialog, QApplication, QComboBox, QStackedWidget
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class ezNPR(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ezNPR, self).__init__()
        loadUi('ezNPRApp.ui', self)
    self.image = None
    self.AppStackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
    self.ExitPushButton.clicked.connect(QDialog.close)
    self.ImagePushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.AppStackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0))
    self.SignaturePushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.AppStackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1))
    self.HelpPushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.AppStackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(2))
    self.SelectImage.clicked.connect(self.load_clicked)

@pyqtSlot()
def load_clicked(self):
    fname, filter = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", os.getenv("HOME"))
    try:
        if fname:
            self.image = cv2.imread(fname)
            #cv2.imshow("First Image", self.image)
            self.display_image()
        else:
            print('No image selected')
            # msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
            # msg.setText("Invalid image type selected. Please select a new image.")
            # msg.setInformativeText("You must select a BMP, JPG, PNG, or TIFF")
            # msg.setWindowTitle("Error Loading Image")
            # msg.setStandardButtons(msg.Ok)
    finally:
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        print("*** print_tb:")
        traceback.print_tb(exc_traceback, limit=5, file=sys.stdout)

def display_image(self):
    displayorig = self.image
    dih, diw = displayorig.shape[:2]
    if dih > diw:
        resizedisplayorig = cv2.resize(displayorig, None, fx=0.2, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    else:
        resizedisplayorig = cv2.resize(displayorig, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    resizedisplayorig = cv2.cvtColor(resizedisplayorig, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    rdih, rdiw = resizedisplayorig.shape[:2]
    #cv2.imshow("Final Image", resizedisplayorig)
    self.importedImageFrame.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(resizedisplayorig))     #Hangs here
    self.importedImageFrame.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter |      QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
    self.inputImageLabel.setText(rdih + " X " + rdiw)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=ezNPR()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: why `super()` in `super(self.loadImage("Wilkerson.png"))`?

Comment: When I copied the code from the original QDesigner UI output file, the slot was nested within the setupUI def. I tried to move the functions to the class level and run them from there thinking it was an issue with the slot being at the same level.

Comment: I got rid of the QDesigner code and thought it would alleviate the problem, but that didn't help. The revised code is below.

Comment: improve your indentation, in python it is very important.